# Is there a way to run one of my apps functions after every minute in blackberry 10?

Tags: listener, blackberry-10

I used to achieve this functionality using real time clock listener and the event clockupdated() in previous blackberry versions.My app received a notification from clockupdated() every minute.After that one of my apps functions would run.I want to achieve the same functionality in blackberry 10.I have a found a bps library clock.h but I couldn't find any such events.
A delay of more than a few minutes is even acceptable.Somebody please help me.